# How to get all historical info from searchTwitter() in R twitteR package

Tags: xml, r, twitter, web-scraping

I'm trying to use `searchTwitter()` to find certain topic on twitter. For example:

```
searchTwitter("#Fast and Furious 7", n = 10000)
```

can only give me a few thousand results. I have also done some research on other topics. It seems that by looking at the date from the result it can only return the result from 9 days before (There are arguments called `since` and `until` which are used to specify time range. But they don't work).

So I'm thinking is there a way to get information for all of this topic? (Or at least I can take control date range).

Apart from this. Can I use xml in R to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: This is a wrapper to the twitter [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) which only allows "queries against the indices of recent or popular Tweets". The publicly available API does not allow you to access all historical tweet data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter provides search for the last few days only.

The cost of keeping the data indexed is too high, given the few users interested. Twitter's business model is live information.

If you want historical data, you will have to buy this from third party providers. I don't remember the name, but a company offering such data was linked from the Twitter web page where they explained this limitation of their search API.